# MySQL fails to start because of init_file '/var/lib/mysql/.-.work.XNDQaWRXUvLyEEJx'

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

I'm trying to figure out why MySQL keeps shutting down every night. Specifically, MySQL restarts itself every night (also unknown reason), but fails on starting itself back up and aborts. Some days it restarts itself successfully and everything works, but most days it doesn't so I've had to make a script to restart it every morning. Around 8-9AM UTC every morning mySQL restarts itself twice, but fails on the 2nd restart. It fails on the start up because it can't find some .-.work init file and I'm not sure why.

There are 2 cases I noticed with MySQL every night:

1. Restarts Successfully. But will says it executes the init file, or not at all.
2. Restarts fail. In this case it's always because it can't find the init file.

Summary info:

- MySQL restarts itself every morning from 8-9AM UTC
- MySQL restarting success: Stop > Start > Stop > Start
- MySQL restarting fail: Stop > Start (Abort/failure) > Stop

Additional info:

- CentOS 6.8
- MySQL 5.7.17

MySQL failing because of init file:

```
2018-02-25T08:45:09.782610Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-02-25T08:45:09.784928Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.17-log) starting as process 11221 ...
2018-02-25T08:45:09.798909Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2018-02-25T08:45:09.798938Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-02-25T08:45:09.798960Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-02-25T08:45:09.798971Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __sync_synchronize() is used for memory barrier
2018-02-25T08:45:09.798992Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-02-25T08:45:09.799007Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-02-25T08:45:09.799444Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-02-25T08:45:09.799600Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-02-25T08:45:09.801717Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-02-25T08:45:09.816978Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-02-25T08:45:09.821022Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2018-02-25T08:45:09.846219Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-02-25T08:45:10.072617Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2018-02-25T08:45:10.072727Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2018-02-25T08:45:10.093784Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2018-02-25T08:45:10.094893Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-02-25T08:45:10.094908Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-02-25T08:45:10.095372Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-02-25T08:45:10.145560Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.17 started; log sequence number 28375479994
2018-02-25T08:45:10.145846Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2018-02-25T08:45:10.145941Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2018-02-25T08:45:10.162499Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180225  1:45:10
2018-02-25T08:45:10.181824Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2018-02-25T08:45:10.186627Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2018-02-25T08:45:10.188420Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2018-02-25T08:45:10.188488Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is`enter code here` not available.
2018-02-25T08:45:10.188521Z 0 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2018-02-25T08:45:10.188545Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2018-02-25T08:45:10.304549Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.replication_connection_status: expected column 'RECEIVED_TRANSACTION_SET' at position 7 to have type longtext, found type text.
2018-02-25T08:45:10.305926Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.replication_group_member_stats: expected column 'COUNT_TRANSACTIONS_ROWS_VALIDATING' at position 6, found 'COUNT_TRANSACTIONS_VALIDATING'.
2018-02-25T08:45:10.311827Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2018-02-25T08:45:10.311944Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check.
2018-02-25T08:45:10.311957Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2018-02-25T08:45:10.880682Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2018-02-25T08:45:10.880729Z 0 [Note] Execution of init_file '/var/lib/mysql/.-.work.gjy3b8Gov_chCz89' started.
2018-02-25T08:45:10.880806Z 0 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: File '/var/lib/mysql/.-.work.gjy3b8Gov_chCz89' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
2018-02-25T08:45:10.880816Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I know the db restarting itself every night is another issue to look into, but I'm not quite sure where to start with this whole problem.Why does it look for that file? How is it being generated? How do I fix it? Any and all help would be appreciated.

(Edit) Reposted here to better meet topic qualifications.

(Edit 2) Here's the my.cnf file:

```
    [mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
log_timestamps = UTC

general_log
general_log_file = /var/log/general_query.log
log_error_verbosity = 3
max_allowed_packet = 256M
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/slow-queries.log
slow-query-log
```

Comment: Is this a default install from the repos?  Do you have any data in the database yet?

Comment: @pgoetz Default install as in I did 'yum install mysql' or something like that? I'll be honest that I don't know how the installation and setup was done as this database existed before me and I was tasked to solve it. There is quite some data in it including our wordpress sites.

Comment: Yeah, that''s what I meant.

Comment: @pgoetz Yes, it was installed from the repos using yum.

Comment: My attempt to help you has already resulted in my reputation being dinged, so I'm loathe to spend any more time on this; particularly since you don't appear to have any idea what you're doing.  It's possible to corrupt the internal mysql tables; the mysql root user can do this.  The simplest way to recover from this is to dump your databases, re-install, and then reload.  If dumping your databases is too complicated, you can attempt to install mysql in, say a VM, and copy the internal tables from there, but that's considerably more complicated.

Comment: @pgoetz That's unfortunate to hear. Thank you for the help, anyways. I was able to fix the internal error tables without dumping, purging, or reloading the db prior to your comment. Now, I'm just waiting to see if it'll still go down every night. Best of luck to you getting your reputation back.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like one of the internal tables isn't set up correctly:

`Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.replication_connection_status: expected column 'RECEIVED_TRANSACTION_SET' at position 7 to have type longtext, found type text.`

I would suggest mysql dumping any databases you have, and dumping user/permissions using

```
mysql -u root -p password --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} --skip-column-names -A | sed 's/$/;/g' > MySQLUserGrants.sql
```

purge the msyql package, reinstall mysql and then restore your databases/users/permissions.

Comment: How do you propose that he start the MySQL server in order to dump the databases?

Comment: Despite the internal tables error, it never stopped MySQL from working whenever I restarted it or when it restarted itself successfully. So, I didn't place much priority on it as the mysterious .-.work file that seems to be aborting it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Did you read the question?  He's not having a problem starting the database; the question was about it shutting down every night.

Comment: Well, this is a suggested solution, speculating about whether or not it will work isn't going to help you much; I would just try it.